# Default Content before Route Resolution

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm re-working a website that has a very nested interface requiring several child views. Think of a shopping site, with paging, results and filters. What I'd like to do is render default content for said children views while the results are being resolved from the back-end. However, I can't find a way to insert default content past the first `<ui-view>`, which of course, makes sense.

To get around this, we are currently using `$broadcast` in the child state controllers. We moved the resolution out of the `resolve` event into the controller, which is working, but requires us to make all of our directives use `$broadcast` as well, or they don't work since the data isn't loaded before they are. It also seems like a very inelegant solution to the issue.

What's weird, is that when I move the `resolve` function into a child view, neither the parent nor it's siblings views load before the results child view loads. I can't understand that whereas I can understand children views not loading before the parent is resolved.

Is there a way we can work around this? Building in broadcasting into all aspects of our code base seems like an extremely poor practice. Is there a way to show children default content before the parent is resolved, or even render child states' views before their controllers are instantiated?

Comment: Your english is very good

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-cloak class:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

Comment: If I use `ng-cloak`, it still doesn't change the behavior of `ui-router` not activating state or sub-states until the resolution has been completed. I can give it a shot, but my guess is that it would only cloak the parent state, which isn't really what I want.